# Unable to run rabbitmq using marathon mesos

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I am unable to run rabbitmq using marathon/mesos framework. I have tried it with rabbitmq images available in docker hub as well as custom build rabbitmmq docker image. In the mesos slave log I see the following error:

E0222 12:38:37.225500 15984 slave.cpp:2344] Failed to update resources for container c02b0067-89c1-4fc1-80b0-0f653b909777 of executor rabbitmq.9ebfc76f-ba61-11e4-85c9-56847afe9799 running task rabbitmq.9ebfc76f-ba61-11e4-85c9-56847afe9799 on status update for terminal task, destroying container: Failed to determine cgroup for the 'cpu' subsystem: Failed to read /proc/13197/cgroup: Failed to open file '/proc/13197/cgroup': No such file or directory

On googling I could find one hit as follows
https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/632

Not sure if this is the issue even I am facing. Anyone tried running rabbitmq using marathon/mesos/docker?

Comment: What versions of Marathon and Mesos are you running and what does your app definition look like?

Comment: marathon version is 0.8.0 and mesos version 0.21.1.  Here is my marathon json

{
  "id": "rabbitmq",
  "cmd": "",
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 512,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "localhost:5000/rabbitmq",
      "network": "BRIDGE"
    }
}
}

Comment: Have you tried running the image on the same host with the docker command directly?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the process went away (likely crashed) before the container was set up. You should check `stdout` and `stderr` to see what happened, and fix the root issue.

Answer (score -1):

"cmd": "", is the like'y culprit. I'd look at couchbase docker containers for a few clues on how to get it working.